# Which process floods my logs with SQLite migration error and how can I cure it?

Tags: xiaomi, logging, sqlite

Phone: Xiaomi Mi Max 3, MIUI 11, Android 10. Using a custom ROM from xiaomi.eu.

The start of the flood is captured in LogCat, it happens every single millisecond, and I'm suspecting some system component. Possibly that `hwservicemanager` which has a couple of entries right before the flood starts, plus the DB migration failure is about a SQL table named `ThermalInfo`. The migration gets into an infinite loop when it fails every time at the 24th step out of 27. However I can go only by what I see int he LogCat.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/F3v0Cha7

Longer log attached in a GitHub issue: https://github.com/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/issues/475

Answer (score 0):

The full logcat output contains the process-id creating the entries (not sure about the logcat you have posted, the format doesn't look like standard logcat output I get from my device).

Using the process-id you can get the app name (or the process path and name) by executing

```
adb shell cat /proc/<process-id>/cmdline
```

In case the logcat entry was created by an app you will get the app name.